# Cant rewrite variable after assigned as infinity Ansi C

Tags: double, infinity

I have double field ypos[] and in some cases instead of double is written into field `-1.#INF00`. I need to rewrite this values with `0.0`, but i cant simply assign zero value, application falls everytime. Is there a way, how to solve this problem?

Comment: Please show a compete code snippet that exhibits your problem, and that we could paste into a compiler and run. Your solution will appear soon after...

Comment: Have you tried disabling floating-point exceptions? I believe `signal(SIGFPE, SIG_IGN)` is the standard C method of doing so

Comment: I do worry whether you are in fact declaring something `double ypos[];` and then assigning `ypos = 0.0` which would make a null pointer... It's not that simple, is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see http://codepad.org/KKYLhbkh for a simple example of how things "should work". Since you have not provided the code that doesn't work, we're guessing here.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define INFINITY (1.0 / 0.0)

int main(void) {
  double a[5] = {INFINITY, 1, 2, INFINITY, 4};
  int ii;
  for(ii = 0; ii < 5; ii++) {
    printf("before: a[%d] is %lf\n", ii, a[ii]);
    if(isinf(a[ii])) a[ii] = 0.0;
    printf("after:  a[%d] is %lf\n", ii, a[ii]);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

As was pointed out in @doynax 's comment, you might want to disable floating point exceptions to stop them from causing your program to keel over.

**edit** if your problem is caused by having taken a logarithm from a number outside of log's domain (i.e. log(x) with x<=0 ), the following code might help:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <math.h>

#define INFINITY (1.0 / 0.0)

int main(void) {
  double a[5] = {INFINITY, 1, 2, INFINITY, 4};
  int ii;
  signal(SIGFPE, SIG_IGN);
  a[2] = log(-1.0);
  for(ii = 0; ii < 5; ii++) {
    printf("before: a[%d] is %lf\n", ii, a[ii]);
    if(isinf(a[ii]) || isnan(a[ii])) a[ii] = 0.0;
    printf("after:  a[%d] is %lf\n", ii, a[ii]);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

You get a different value for `log(0.0)` (namely `-Inf`) and for `log(-1.0)` (namely `nan`). The above code shows how to deal with either of these.

Answer (score 1):

A geuess that your problem is somewhere else. Can you write 0.0 before INF is written?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry guys, I've solving this problem about 2 hours and tried to ask here but I've made a solution by comparing value of variable with -DBL_MAX. But thank you all for try.